# I want to start service using motion sensor

Tags: android, kotlin, background-process, android-sensors

I want the service to start running in background when there is any motion deducted by the android and stop the service when there is no movement. I am not sure how to do that. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: That's not going to be possible.  First off, to detect motion you'd already need to be running.  Your app would need to be in the background to at least get location (or accelerometer, whichever you use) events in order to do whatever it is you want to do when you detect motion.  Secondly, you cant really have a long term background service in Android anymore.  You can have a foreground service do it, but even then its not reliable-  it can be killed by the OS at any time.  And if the screen is off you're going into Doze mode and will only be able to  run once every 15minutes or so.

Comment: okay so I am trying to get the user location in background and post the geo point to firebase what would be the best approach to do it